# What key changes in the 2024 Golden Globe Awards led to increased viewership compared to the previous year?

Tags: awards, golden-globes

I've noticed a significant surge in the viewership and interest surrounding the 2024 Golden Globe Awards compared to last year. This piqued my curiosity, and I'm keen to understand what specific changes or factors contributed to this increased attention.

1. Were there any notable modifications in the award categories, presentation format, or eligibility criteria that made this year's event more appealing?
2. Did the Golden Globes incorporate any unique themes, social causes, or technological advancements that could have enhanced its appeal?

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.forbes.com/sites/tonifitzgerald/2023/11/21/golden-globes-makeover-continues-with-move-to-cbs-new-categories-and-other-changes/amp/